# QToolButton don't make nothing when I click it

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I am trying to make a browser, but the add new tab button is not working.I can see it but I when I try to click it it doesn't make nothing!
It don't return anything.
The code:

```py
self.add_new = QToolButton(
        self,
        text="+",
        triggered=lambda: self.add_new_tab,
        shortcut=QKeySequence.AddTab,
    )

def add_new_tab(self):
    new = BrowserTab(self)
    new.browser.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"))
    self.add_tab(new)
```

You can find more at [Github](https://github.com/samdug2011/silvercat-browser)

Comment: Please be more precise with the title of your questions: the button *can* be clicked, the problem is that it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that for the triggered callback, you have it set to a lambda which has a function without parenthesis on it. Try one of these instead:

```
triggered=self.add_new_tab
triggered=lambda: self.add_new_tab()   # only if you want to pass in parameters
```

The triggered callback will automatically "call" the function you give it, so if you give it a lambda with a function that has no parenthesis on it, the lambda will get called, but the function inside won't.

Comment: I ave tried the `triggered=self.add_new_tab` but it don't work.

Comment: @samdug Try putting some print statements at the start of self.add_new_tab. Do they ever get printed when you click the button?

Comment: @samdug I suggest you to edit your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: No, they don't !!

Comment: @samdug Are you sure `triggered` is even the right keyword for a QToolButton? Have you tried `clicked` instead? If that doesn't work either, maybe try connecting the QToolButton on a separate line by doing `self.add_new.clicked.connect(self.add_new_tab)`